# Calling API based on intervals returned as a response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, response

Hello I was currently trying a challenge in which I am supposed to make post and put  call to  an api.

So I am trying a challenge that I got a month ago:

```
http://challenge.com/challenges?nickname=anythinghere `
```

I first need to make a post request at this endpoint  in order to receive an ID
this is the res structure

```
id: 'fSkslN++h0BGxtMwlS/OB+OZW+NaIfLqP7dpM0+Zj+WNipwKJMSJJO2wAq4JI5Zs',
  actives_at: 1700583237548,
  called_at: 1700583236759,
  total_diff: 0
```

2. I then need to use the ID by passing it inside the header as  "X-Challenge-Id": {passing the id I got as a response here} on this endpoint

```
http://challenge.com/challenges
```

the method is set to PUT this time and send a request to this endpoint at the scheduled invocation time.
3)Then I need to make the calls again and again till total_diff here reaches more than 500ms
4) upon performing this all correctly the res given is changed to something like this

```
{
   "result": {
     "attempts": 100,
     "url": "/xxxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

now I am confused since in my case after I pass in the id as a header and then call the endpoint it is only able to make the call 2 or 1 times which results in the challenge failing and the URL being returned as undefined however, My friend was able to make then 2000 calls? can someone help?

I actually was not able to write any code 1 month ago regarding this however I feel like I am closer. Can someone help me with this? I will write my current code below

```js
async function intervalCall() {
  try {
    const startResponse = await fetch(
      "http://example/challenges",
      { method: "POST" }
    ); //make the initial fetch call to start the challenge
    const dataRes = await startResponse.json();
    console.log(dataRes);

    // {
    //   id: 'unique ID',
    //   actives_at: 1700570652300,
    //   called_at: 1700570651628,
    //   total_diff: 0
    // }

    let dataResId = dataRes.id;
    let currentInterval = dataRes.total_diff;

    if (currentInterval <= 500) {
      const startResponsePut = await fetch(
        "http://example/challenges",
        { method: "PUT", headers: { "X-Challenge-Id": dataResId } }
      ); //make the PUT call with the challenge id untill the differrence is >500
      const responsePutJson = await startResponsePut.json();
      console.log(responsePutJson);
      currentInterval += dataRes.total_diff;
    } else {
      console.log("Challenge interval exceeds 500");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
}

// Call the function
intervalCall();
```

**On success, returned response**

```
{
   "result": {
     "attempts": 100,
     "url": "/xxxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

**So basically I need to call the challenges endpoint after putting the nickname in it to get the unique ID and then make a PUT method call again and again till the difference reaches more than 500ms inside the given response.**